# A map function that operates on pairs

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function which is like `map`, but which takes functions of type `(a, a) -> b` as its first argument. However, I get the error

```
 <interactive>:474:11: error:
Parse error in pattern: \ (x, y) -> f x y
```

with the following code:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| mappairs :: ((a, a) -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
Prelude| mappairs (\(x,y) -> f x y) xs = foldr (\(x, y) acc -> (f x y : acc)) [] xs 
Prelude| :}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What would you expect to be the result of `mappairs (\(x,y) -> x-y) [5]`? This call type checks according to your signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern:

```
\(x,y) -> f x y
```

in the clause:

```
mappairs (\(x,y) -> f x y) xs = foldr (\(x, y) acc -> (f x y : acc)) [] xs
```

is indeed not valid, since `(->)` is not a data constructor.

You can however use [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) here:

```
mappairs :: ((a, a) -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mappairs _ [] = []
mappairs f xa@(_:xs) = zipWith (curry f) xa xs
```

For example:

```
> mappairs (\(x,y) -> x+y) [1,4,2,5]
[5,6,7]
```

But it looks more "*Haskell-ish*" to omit the tuples, and thus use a function directly:

```
mappairs :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mappairs _ [] = []
mappairs f xa@(_:xs) = zipWith f xa xs
```

Comment: I tried `mappairs :: ((a, a) -> b) -> [a] -> [b] mappairs f xs = foldr (\(x, y) acc -> (f x y : acc)) [] xs` and I receive the error

Comment: `<interactive>:492:40: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ t0 -> b
    • The function ‘f’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘(a, a) -> b’ has only one
      In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘f x y’
      In the expression: (f x y : acc)
    • Relevant bindings include
        acc :: [b] (bound at <interactive>:492:32)
        y :: t0 (bound at <interactive>:492:29)
        f :: (a, a) -> b (bound at <interactive>:492:10)
        mappairs :: ((a, a) -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
          (bound at <interactive>:492:1)`

Comment: `<interactive>:492:57: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        a ~ ((a, a), t0)
      Expected type: [((a, a), t0)]
        Actual type: [a]
    • In the third argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘xs’
      In the expression: foldr (\ (x, y) acc -> (f x y : acc)) [] xs
      In an equation for ‘mappairs’:
          mappairs f xs = foldr (\ (x, y) acc -> (f x y : acc)) [] xs
    • Relevant bindings include`

Comment: `xs :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:492:12)
        f :: (a, a) -> b (bound at <interactive>:492:10)
        mappairs :: ((a, a) -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
          (bound at <interactive>:492:1)`

Comment: @user65526: hold on, the type should be `((a, a) -> b) -> [(a, a)] -> [b]` (or even `((a, b) -> c) -> [(a, b)] -> [c]`.

Comment: But the idea was to have something like `map`, but which took a binary function as its first argument and a list (not a list of tuples) as its second argument.

Comment: @user65526: and what would be the semantics of that function? Right now you only define the types, but there are an infinite amount of functions with the same type.

Comment: It would add the first member of the tuple to the second, then the third to the second and first, then the fourth to the first three...

Comment: @user65526 That doesn't sound like it has much to do with tuples. Are you perhaps looking for Data.List.scanl?